# How to reorder vertex index?

Tags: mesh, particles, vertices

I have a particle system that uses a mesh as an emitter. It emits from the Vertices in a non-random order, and (I assume) it uses the vertex index to determine that order.

It works as intended, with the particles appearing in an orderly fashion, except for one thing: the top line appears first, then it starts from the bottom and makes its way to the top.

[image]

(Notice how the top line is already there and the rest of the particles are still appearing from bottom to top)

I don't want the top line to appear first. I want it to start from the bottom and work its way to the top, and the top line is the last one that should appear.
For that I guess I need to change the indices of the top vertices so they are last and not first.
Any way I can do that? It can be manually, although I would prefer an 'automatic' solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried deleting this row in edit mode and re-extruding it ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. The particles still spawn in the top line first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to **Mesh** ⇾ **Sort elements** and then try available options. I suppose  **Reverse** is that you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: I had to try a few options but eventually one worked as intended. Thanks!